# angularJS filter for two condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I  have this json array for category

```
$scope.categories=     [{
         "name": "Sport",
         "value":"SPORT",
        "image": "images/Layer-1.png"
        },{
         "name": "Theater",
         "value":"THEATER",
        "image": "images/Layer-2.png"
        },{
         "name": "Restaurant",
         "value":"RESTAURANT",
        "image": "images/Layer-3.png"
        },{
         "name": "Concert",
         "value":"CONCERT",
        "image": "images/Layer-4.png"
        },{
         "name": "Nightlife",
         "value":"THEATER",
        "image": "images/Layer-2.png"
        }];
```

which i send through this function on ng-click

```
 $scope.sendCategory = function(category) {

     $scope.search = category;
     //alert(category);



  };
```

I have this in HTML for filter

```
filter:{itemType:search}
```

Its working perfectly . Now i want to make it work like when category is "nightlife" it shows the concert and theater, cause none of data have itemType = nightlife;
So how to make it like for other it work as it is working but for night life search will be both concert and theater

Comment: why you dont writing custom filter ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it using a filter function. Something like this:

```
filter:function(value){return ['concert','theater'].indexOf(value.itemType) !== -1;}
```

Comment: How to use it ? where should i write these lines

Comment: @AshishNautiyal: seriously, you should read more documentation, filter function is a very helpful feature, check this link, it shows how to write filter functions, https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Comment: And the reference doc with a few examples: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter